# Structuremap and base controller in MVC4: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I'm using Structuremap for DI, setting it up with a bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper {
    public static void ConfigureDependencies() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.AddRegistry<ControllerRegistry>());
    }
    public class ControllerRegistry : Registry {
        public ControllerRegistry(){
            For<IService1>().Use<Service1>();
            For<IService2>().Use<Service2>();
            For<IService3>().Use<Service3>();
        }
    }
}
```

In the file "EngineFactory.cs" I have this:

```
public class EngineFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

I have two controllers with the appropiate views:

**Login/Index:**

This is a simple page where people can login. Nothing fancy and the DI is working perfect. As soon as someone has logged in, he/she is redirected to Home/Index:

**Home/Index:**

This is where the problem occurs. The controller has a base controller, looking something like this:

```
public class HomeController : MyBaseController{
    public HomeController(IService1 myService) : base(myService){
        // Do something cool
    }
```

The code for MyBaseController:

```
public class MyBaseController: Controller {
    public MyBaseController(IService1 myService){
        // Do something cools... Please?
    }
}
```

This gives errors on the home-controller:
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

When I remove the base controller from the home-controller (and make it build again), it works fine.

I searched Google and stackoverflow and this is what I tried, but did not work:

**1**:

```
try {
    return (controllerType == null)
        ? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType)
        : ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
} catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
}
```

Gives error:
The IControllerFactory 'My.Application.App_Start.EngineFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'.

**2**:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

No effect

**3**:

```
if (controllerType == null)
    return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
var controller = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
return (IController)controller;
```

Other error:
Source cannot be found
/Home

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code that you provide here, it hides somewhere else in your services or the controllers' constructors . I've checked it, it works fine.

Comment: So, maybe I'm looking in the wrong place... Humm. I will make a new project with less code to check it out. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks for now

Comment: What does the constructor for the IService1 implementation look like?  It could be that the implementation has a dependency that can't be resolved.  Also, you can usually find exactly what is trying to get resolved but can't by digging into the InnerExceptions.  It can be a few deep before you find the real issue.

Comment: A new, empty MVC project with the above code works like a charm. After some trying to implement the DI in the current situation (and debugging like my life depended on it)... I gave up. I could not find the problem. Sometimes you have to accept your loss and move on. In my case that means I needed to start over again. It took me 4 hours, but I'm finally done and it works like I want it to.